# Экспорт анимации из Spine в Box2D

Tags: c++, анимация, box2d

Будет готовая анимация персонажа в Spine, её можно экспортировать в json файл и ещё какие-то. Есть тестовый проект в Box2D (Testbed тот что). Нужно к телу применить анимацию, но я совершенно не знаю, как. На официальном сайте и github spine-а есть библиотеки для всяких игровых движков, но для Box2D нет. Не могли бы вы помочь?

Comment: ...потому что Box2D это **физический** движок, а не игровой.

Comment: Ну могу же я поступить так: заставить двигаться формы в box2D, повторяя движения из анимации, чтобы они отображались графически на экране позже?